# Do I need a win streak?

Tags: code-golf, number, rational-numbers

You have played \$N\$ matches in some game where each match can only result in one of the two outcomes: win or loss. Currently, you have \$W\$ wins. You want to have a win percentage of \$P\$ or more, **playing as few matches as possible**. Output the minimum win streak that you need. Assume the current win streak is at \$0\$.

For example: If \$N=10, W=2, P=50\$, then  you can win \$6\$ matches in a row, bringing your win percentage to \$\frac{2+6}{10+6} = \frac{8}{16} = 50\%\$. You cannot have a win percentage of \$50\$ or more earlier than this. So the answer for this case is \$6\$.

## Examples

```
W, N, P ->
2, 10, 50%      -> 6
3, 15, 50%      -> 9
35, 48, 0.75    -> 4
19, 21, 0.91    -> 2
9, 10, 50%      -> 0
0, 1, 1/100     -> 1
43, 281, 24/100 -> 33
0, 6, 52%       -> 7
```

## Rules

- \$N\$ and \$W\$ will be integers with \$0 \le W < N\$.
- The percentage \$P\$ will be an integer between \$1\$ and \$100\$ inclusive. You can also choose to take a decimal value between \$0\$ and \$1\$ inclusive instead, which will contain no more than \$2\$ decimal places, or take it as a fraction.
- You can take the inputs in any convenient format.
- Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22151/77516)

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 35 bytes

```python
lambda w,n,p:-min(0,(w-p*n)//(1-p))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7BCsIwDMbxu0/RYyLp1mSdroJv4mUiw4GrRQZjT1@7glDR648/XxLW@f70TRzOl/jop@utVwt5Cic9jR4MwaLD3mNdA@uAGMNr9DMMIKTYkDJVi7j7YJOw/cEkttv0WDI7UsIbOy7Y/dtNkEtTljZdky672O/4kAckvfsG)

-4 bytes thanks to pajonk

Some simple math: if \$X\$ is the number of wins we need, then we have:

\$\frac{W+X}{N+X}\geq P\$

\$W+X\geq PN+PX\$

\$X-PX\geq PN-W\$

\$X(1-P)\geq PN-W\$

Since \$P<1\$, then \$1-P>0\$, so we can divide from both sides without division by zero or flipping the sign.

\$X\geq\frac{PN-W}{1-P}\$

Comment: Since \$P<1\$ it would IMHO be clearer to write \$X\geq\frac{PN-W}{1-P}\$.

Comment: @Neil Ah, that's true. I think this is a bit clearer now. Thanks :)

Comment: Shouldn't this work? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7BCsIwDMbxu0/RYyLp1mSdroJv4mUiw4GrRQZjT1@7glDR648/XxLW@f70TRzOl/jop@utVwt5Cic9jR4MwaLD3mNdA@uAGMNr9DMMIKTYkDJVi7j7YJOw/cEkttv0WDI7UsIbOy7Y/dtNkEtTljZdky672O/4kAckvfsG "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @pajonk It does seem to. Well spotted; thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>13</s> <s>15</s> 11 bytes

```
∞<.Δ¹+.«/²@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8G71zUw7t1NY7tFr/0CaH//@jjXQUDA1iuQz0TAE)

Why aren't I using Vyxal? Because I'm leaving the chance for others so they can claim the bounty.

*+2 due to bug fix :(*

*but -4 thanks to @ovs*

### Explained (old)

```python
∞0š.ΔD²+s¹+s/³@
∞0š.Δ            # get the first integer n where:
     D²+s¹+s/    #     (wins + n) / (matches + n)
             ³@  #     >= percentage
```

Comment: Instead of prepending a `0` you can decrement every integer with `<`.

Comment: [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8G71zUw7t1NY7tFr/0CaH//@jjXQUDA1iuQz0TAE) with a slightly different input format.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
Ḣ_Ḣ×$÷’Ċ»0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjkXxQHx4usrh7Y8aZh7pOrTb4P/h9kdNa/7/jzbSUTA00FEw0DON1VGINgbyTBE8INPEAsQ1B/MNLXUUjAxBfEtDEN8SRS@QBZYzAMuZAI0ysgALGJlApc3Aao1iAQ)

### Explanation

This uses the same formula as my [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224352): \$X\geq\frac{W-PN}{P-1}\$

Takes the input as a list of three numbers, \$W,N,P\$.

```
Ḣ_Ḣ×$÷’Ċ»0  Main Link
Ḣ           W (pops from the list)
 _          minus
  Ḣ×$       N (pops from the list) times the list (now only has P)
     ÷’     divided by (P - 1)
       Ċ    ceiling
        »0  maximum of that and 0
```

### In-depth explanation

This is an even more in-depth explanation of this answer. If you are familiar with Jelly, you should probably skip this. I won't do these often.

Since this link is called with one argument each time, it is a monadic chain. Hence, as we walk down the chain, the following patterns are matched in this order: `dyad-monad`, `dyad-nilad`, `nilad-dyad`, `dyad`, and `monad` (nilads take 0 arguments; you can think of them as constants) (monads take 1 argument) (dyads take 2 arguments).

Since the link doesn't start with a nilad, the evaluation value starts equal to the argument, `[W, N, P]`.

First, we see `Ḣ`, a monad meaning "pop and return the first element". This matches the last rule, so it applies as a monad to the current value, which is `[W, N, P]`. Thus, the current value is now `W`, and this also modifies the left argument object itself to `[N, P]`.

Here, it is important to note the function of `$` - it takes the last two links and groups them into a monadic link. Here, the two links are `Ḣ` and `×`. We'll get back to this.

Next, we see `_`, a dyad (subtraction). It is followed by a monad, namely the one formed by the `$` grouping two links, thus matching the first pattern. The dyad-monad pattern, if we have some dyad `+` and some monad `F`, computes `v + F(a)` where `v` is the current value and `a` is the right argument. Thus, this computes `W - F([N, P])`. Here, `F(a)` computes `Ḣ×` as a monadic chain whose argument is `a = [N, P]`. The value starts at `v = [N, P]` as well.

The first link is a monad and thus the value becomes `N`. Also, since "pop" mutates, the argument (to both the sub-link and the main link) is now `[P]`. Then, the second link is a dyad and nothing else follows, so the value becomes `N × [P]` which is `[NP]`. This is a singleton list, not a value, but that's fine because everything else vectorizes.

Now, the value is `W - [NP]` which vectorizes to `[W - NP]`, and the argumnt is `[P]` since it was mutated within the sub-link.

`÷’` is a dyad-monad chain, which computes `[W - NP] ÷ P÷’`. `’` decrements, so this computes `[W - NP] ÷ (P - 1)`, which vectorizes to `[(W - NP) / (P - 1)]`.

Penultimately, `Ċ` is a monad meaning "ceiling", which just rounds all of these values up. Finally, `»0` is a dyad-nilad chain which takes the maximum of this value and 0, thus preventing negative outputs.

Here's a shitty hand-drawn visualization of how chaining works out here:

[image]

Comment: And you're sure that a "find first n where" approach wouldn't be shorter?

Comment: @Lyxal I can't say for sure that a solution of that form wouldn't be shorter, but I haven't found one yet.

Comment: @Lyxal [it's shorter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224364/66833)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>45</s> <s>43</s> <s>42</s> 38 bytes

*Edit: simultaneous discovery of -1 byte by Kirill L., and then -4 bytes thanks to pajonk*

```r
function(W,N,P)-min((W-P*N)%/%(1-P),0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc/RCoIwFAbge5/iQAhbnNk2N3UX9QjinZcSuWJEC8zo8W12I5I719//859h@jjvnb91r3Gw53vnre1tf5yub38Z3dOTFmtsKHs4T0jLmn1N00NKBGsocrqdJhJBcIRMw@8o7ICdoEi2dR60/tMmpgNVFQLPSr1oFdHCIEgxayMWLSPabO7mER1kaM64WGkR0Sq8Kas5INWi8zxeXsxL5Kq8TJLpCw)

Comment: @KirilL Ha!  I was just editing this in while you commented.  You get half the credit!  Thanks anyway!

Comment: Shouldn't this work in principle? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc/RCoIwFAbge5/iQAhbnNk2N3UX9QjinZcSuWJEC8zo8W12I5I719//859h@jjvnb91r3Gw53vnre1tf5yub38Z3dOTFmtsKHs4T0jLmn1N00NKBGsocrqdJhJBcIRMw@8o7ICdoEi2dR60/tMmpgNVFQLPSr1oFdHCIEgxayMWLSPabO7mER1kaM64WGkR0Sq8Kas5INWi8zxeXsxL5Kq8TJLpCw "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @pajonk - Er, rather embarassing that I didn't spot that.  Thanks.  Do you want to just post it & be the winner?  I feel rather ashamed...

Comment: Nah, thanks - let's treat it the same as with the [python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224352/55372) :)

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 44 bytes

Every answer of [Wasif](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224354/80745) inspires me to make the right one. Thanks.

```powershell
param($w,$n,$p)for(;$w++/$n++-lt$p){$k++}+$k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDNTsMwEITvfoo9GJTILo3z0zZCSJV4ABA9ogqFsKXQ/BE7ClLJs4d1khYQe7K/2ZmRtipbrPUes6znO7iBY18ldZI7vJW8kLxyd2XtXPNWiDkvhJhlhtiRH4ToBD/0HWNrhzHp@BKUJ8G7imAcCQuXeEA8@svjgRMMV1ZYRhMPLVexBF9ZHquJ@5bH//M9y4nRtqPmyvPckSvLQyr2V1byw0GTEASTYUE08k8OCUuXMRe@4AKOzEbw9q3QEniemHSP9lVhnWJhklekD35WmBp8oWvxp9FQo24yQ@CSjjjYz@7f5mH58X5z22hT5nfP75SzXY@ldjZNmqLWNnhKnOHHT@F57@FUN60NQse6/hs)

Answer (score 3):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 39 bytes

```clj
#(max(Math/ceil(/(-(* %2%)%3)(- 1%)))0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc5BDoIwEAXQfU8xiWkyNSBtAYVDeIKmCwIlaipgQYOnry0mxt1/@TOTae14ezrjsTM99H6H92bFc7NcstZcLWaY4h6opIzmDFMQlDHGmWcEu3E2D1CwKqJkAoInwA@lJioPKH8IqaiiTpGiTkCKyFoE1v97IWwNj00Rrshqsyy@5XEblJpoTXBy12GxA2AzTfYNPaAzL@NmA2v4kPkP)

Takes arguments in reverse order compared to the provided test cases (\$P, N, W\$).

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
0+÷/:⁴ʋ1#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99A@/B2fatHjVtOdRsq////30hHwdDgv4GeKQA)

Full program that takes `[w, n]` on the left and `P` on the right.

### How it works

```
0+÷/:⁴ʋ1# - Main link. Takes [w, n] on the left and P on the right
      ʋ   - Previous 4 links as a dyad f(x, [w, n]):
 +        -   Yield [w+x, n+x]
  ÷/      -   Yield (w+x)÷(n+x)
     ⁴    -   Yield P
    :     -   Floor divide (w+x)÷(n+x) by P,
               returning 0 if P < (w+x)÷(n+x), and 1 otherwise
0      1# - Count up x = 0, 1, 2, ..., and find the first x such that f(x, [w, n]) is 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 51 bytes

```powershell
param($w,$n,$p)while(($w+$k)/($n+$k)-lt$p){$k+=1}$k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQ6VcRyVPR6VAszwjMydVA8jXVsnW1NdQyQPRujklQKlqlWxtW8Nalez///8b/Tc0@G@gZwoA)

What? It beat my python answer? oO

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>44</s> <s>40</s> 34 bytes

```js
f=(w,n,p)=>w/n>=p?0:f(w+1,n+1,p)+1
```

Takes all three parameters as integers except `p` which is a decimal.

*-4 bytes, thanks to @DominicvanEssen*
*-6 bytes, thanks to @Arnauld*

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##DcNRCoAgDADQ60xcpkE/gXUWMY1CtpGRx7cevCu8ocb7lGcg3lPv2UNDQlF@bSOtXja7ZGjaIf1FadcjU@WSTOEDMkzoLJpZqf4B)

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by taking p as a fraction instead of a percentage...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Oh yeah that's right

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVajXCdPp0DT1q5cP8@mwF63Lk2jXNtQJw@ICzStDP4n5@cV5@ek6uXkp2ukaRjpGBro6Jlqav4HAA), or [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVajXCdPp0DT1q5cP8@mQE1Nty5No1zbUCcPiAs0/yfn5xXn56Tq5eSna6RpGOkYGujomWpq/gcA) if you don't mind returning **false** instead of **0**.

Comment: [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##dc9NDoIwEAXgvaeYFWlDoZ3S8pNY7mIQiIYUIkZ2Xh2LRlDQ3Sy@vPfmfLgd@uJy6q6BbY/lWJmxM3ltyMAsNfnA7b7zvOBek8FHZn2kY9Havm3KsGlrUhERagCgRDJAAdNJgXOId79Z5JheWLZhiX4yzUClM1MbluHEMGMgcWbyT2n2vU2sGHIUwjHhGCwMV0yqyVGi3A8yxTeLom2rhFdc/BGXjA8) by taking `(p)(w,n)`.

Comment: @Arnauld I'll go with your 33 byte suggestion because I prefer its I/O formats.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 34 bytes

```ruby
->w,n,p{[0,-(w-p*n).div(1-p)].max}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf165cJ0@noDraQEdXo1y3QCtPUy8ls0zDULdAM1YvN7Gi9n@BQlq0kY6CoYGOgoGeaSwXiG8M5Jsi84EcEwuQgDlUxNBSR8HIECRiaQgRsUQzA8gGyxtA5U2AhhpZgIWMTOBKzMA6jGL/AwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 68 bytes

```
\d+
$*
\G1
100$*
1(?=1*,(1*)%)
$1
+`^(1*,)(1+\1(1+))
100$*1$1$3$2_
_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYo7DsIwFAT7dw4/yXa28PoDcYEocwmLBAkKGgqU@xujiGY1s5rPc3@9713tsvX2mMR4aQuFIQyivV7oYemdOjGUabsNgbOcGsc4d5Q0NMnEVdbeIxhQgkoCywEFeca5qLAiEpUq9V8FEMNzQpyJmH/PCSXqFw) Link includes test cases. Takes `P` as a percentage (including `%` sign). Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert `W`, `N` and `P` to unary.

```
\G1
100$*
```

Multiply `W` by `100`.

```
1(?=1*,(1*)%)
$1
```

Multiply `N` by `P`.

```
+`^(1*,)(1+\1(1+))
```

While `100W<NP`...

```
100$*1$1$3$2_
```

increment `W` and `N`, i.e. add `100` to `100W` and `P` to `NP`.

```
_
```

Count the number of increments made.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 37 bytes

```hs
(n,w)#p|100*w<p*n=1+(n+1,w+1)#p|1>0=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RdBLCsIwEAbgvacY6iYxIyZtfVSMJ1ARXLioIl0UFGsMtZKNd68ToxYSkv9jZgg5F49rWVVtyww63rcvJeXALezAaCWYEQqdUB9fSi3bW3ExoOFW2PUJ7LPZNfXKQB7t5xAJ8TjfHTghIsBNB4YAYduB9RV6@c@1z6NfZLXWJSc6mOjFHBq0WPLFMO8BsBhBSYQx7QlHLwnJOEj2FYrpDGHqz0AqQ4gVVdCOA2XdJBmEbiqskFMaHc98R4qQJP@iCXXRO6b8iFXZQK2/X3ds3w)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 31 bytes

```
f(W,N,P)=-min(-(P*N-W)\(1-P),0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcwxDsMgDEDRPSexK4OwgSQMXCFiy9KlSyqGRijq/SlR1ZL16euXx5HVs9S6wUoLJYzqlXdQkG6LWvEOrBKSwVqOvL9hAyE2pD3GOOLwQ0vsvxgu6MnNpKeTXWcOJEw6cGPpHP5f09FQK81ZckdnSebm4ppbe63HdpCmEw71Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 55 bytes

```python
f=lambda w,n,p,c=0:(w+c)/(n+c)>=p and c or f(w,n,p,c+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRoVwnT6dAJ9nWwEqjXDtZU18jD0ja2RYoJOalKCQr5BcppGlA1Wgbav4vKMrMK9FI0zDSMTTQ0TPV1PwPAA)

Simple recursion, I am beaten by few minutes....

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＮζ≔⁰εＷ‹⁺θε×ζ⁺ηε≦⊕εＩε
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYxBCsIwFET3OUWWX4hS0KLQlXRVUOnCC8T4MYEktvmJQi8fU3Uhzu49ZkZpGdRd2pw7P6R4Su6CAcZFw35Z//FUeE9kbh4qwbHQUxuLHA5IBL1NBOPsBT8bhwST4G@pZ1nCj3L47juvAjr0Ea@fpz4YH6GVFKF0m5zXNdvsWLXa1nn5sC8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮηＮζ
```

Input `W`, `N` and `P`.

```
≔⁰ε
```

Start with `X=0`.

```
Ｗ‹⁺θε×ζ⁺ηε
```

Until we reach the desired win percentage...

```
≦⊕ε
```

... increment `X`.

```
Ｉε
```

Output `X`.

A port of @hyper-neutrino's solutions is of course much shorter at 13 bytes:

```
Ｉ⌈⟦⁰±÷⁻×ＮＮＮ⊖θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcixCsJADADQvV/RMYEqhVoUHO3i0NLBTRzOa9BAc@pdrvj30VVwfM/fXfQPN5uNkYPCwSWF3r1ZssC5rsqBbk4JjkE7Xngi6DnkBCcWSt99Zh2yXCkCVuUP/7gjH0koKE3wQrwg4t6sXm/bYrMrmtZWy/wB) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input in the order `P`, `N`, `W`. Explanation:

```
        Ｎ       `P` as a number
       ×        Multiplied by
         Ｎ      `N` as a number
      ⁻         Subtract
          Ｎ     `W` as a number
     ÷          Floor divided by
           ⊖θ   `P` decremented
    ±           Negated
 ⌈⟦⁰            Maximum of that and 0
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
@°*L¨V°*W}a
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QLAqTKhWsCpXfWE&input=MgoxMAo1MA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 2.4.1](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
λ¹+ɖ⁰≥;ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=5&code=%CE%BB%C2%B9%2B%C9%96%E2%81%B0%E2%89%A5%3B%E1%B9%85&inputs=%5B2%2C%2010%5D%0A0.5&header=&footer=)
Here's what I managed to come up with. It doesn't seem like  anyone else is going to give this a go using Vyxal, so here's my solution.

### Explained

```
λ¹+ɖ⁰≥;ṅ
λ        # start a lambda that, given a single argument "n":
 ¹+      #     adds n to the list [wins, matches]
   ɖ     #     reduces that list by division
    ⁰≥;  #    and returns whether that number is greater than the percentage
       ṅ # take that lambda, and find the first integer (starting at 0) where it evaluates as truthy
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 25 bytes

```
0//.x_/;x+#-##2<x#3:>x+1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b730BfX68iXt@6QltZV1nZyKZC2djKrkLbUO1/QFFmXkm0sq5dmoODcqxaXXByYl5dNVe1gpGOgqGBjoKeaa0OkGcM5JnCeMZAlokFkGcO5hpa6igYGQK5loZgtZYoOoEsBZCkAVjSxFjHyALENTKBy5qB1BrVctX@BwA)

We can also directly compute the number of needed wins:

#### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 25 bytes

```
⌈Min[#-##2,0]/--+#3⌉&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7/1FPh29mXrSyrrKykY5BrL6urray8aOeTrX/AUWZeSVACbs0BwflWLW64OTEvLpqrmoFIx0FQwMdBT3TWh0gzxjIM4XxjIEsEwsgzxzMNbTUUTAyBHItDcFqLVF0AlkKIEkDsKSJsY6RBYhrZAKXNQOpNarlqv0PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [CSASM v2.4.0.1](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.4.0.1), 123 bytes

A function which pops three values from the stack (`[N, W, P]`) and pushes the result as an `f64`.
The function expects the types of all three values to be `f64`.

```
.include <stdmath>
func a:
pop $3
pop $2
pop $1
push $3
dup
push $2
swap
push $1
mul
sub
neg
swap
push 1.0
sub
div
neg
push 0.0
call max
ret
end
```

**Explanation + Full Program:**

````
.include <stdmath>

func main:
    ; Get the three inputs
    in "N: "
    conv f64

    in "W: "
    conv f64

    in "P: "
    conv f64

    call a

    ; Truncate the result and print it
    conv i32
    push "Wins needed: "
    swap
    add
    print.n

    ret
end

func a:
    pop $3 ; P
    pop $2 ; W
    pop $1 ; N

    push $3
    ; [ P ]
    dup
    ; [ P, P ]

    push $2
    ; [ P, P, W ]
    swap
    ; [ P, W, P ]
    push $1
    ; [ P, W, P, N ]
    mul
    ; [ P, W, P*N ]
    sub
    ; [ P, W-P*N ]
    neg
    ; [ P, P*N-W ]
    swap
    ; [ P*N-W, P ]
    push 1.0
    ; [ P*N-W, P, 1 ]
    sub
    ; [ P*N-W, P-1 ]
    div
    ; [ (P*N-W)/(P-1) ]
    neg
    ; [ -(P*N-W)/(P-1) ]
    push 0.0
    call max

    ret
end
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes `P` as a decimal.

```
@°/V°<W}f
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QLAvVrA8V31m&input=NDMgMjgxIC4yNA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 28 bytes

Takes `P` as a decimal and outputs `false` for `0`.

```javascript
w=>n=>g=p=>w++/n++<p&&g(p)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc3BCsIwDIDhuw8yEoq6xk5bMH2XIWzMQwlzbI9f04NQx475@JO8@7X/vOZJlvPq88B545g4jiwcN2OuyZinNM0IgsZmmae0wACEYFuES4d4@tlNrdubgvOKj1ptQCCrGmyl4eCmzqVr687pI/KFyf2n97JNiPkL)